# Universal App Data Binding accessing data from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm working on a small app at the moment, and ran into a slight obstacle.

The task is to grab a list of items (title, url, date) from an online source, and display them.
Display is working, but I want the items to launch a LaunchUriAsync() command with the item's URL.

The bound list is an ObservableCollection, the view is a simple ListBox with a custom ItemTemplate (Stack Panel and TextBox).

How can one achieve the effect described?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, just a few minutes after posting I've realized I was going at it from the wrong angle.
Instead of assigning a "Tapped" event to the StackPanel, there's a generic ItemClick event for the ListBox, which can access the bound object via e.ClickedItem (plus casting).